# Authentication using Django Rest + JWT during tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework, jwt

question here. I'm having trouble testing my login feature using DRF + JWT. It all works OK outside of test environment, I can login as an admin using exact same method and I get my token back.

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from rest_framework.test import RequestsClient




TEST_USER = {
    'username': 'test1',
    'email': 'test@test.com',
    'password': 'qwe123qwe',
}
BASE_URL = 'http://testserver/'
API_LOGIN = 'http://testserver/' + 'api-token-auth/'


class TestAuthentication(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        User.objects.create(**TEST_USER)
        self.requests = RequestsClient()

    def test_user_can_login(self):
        user = User.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.count(), 1)
        response = self.requests.post(API_LOGIN, TEST_USER)
        print(response.content)
```

the output is:

> b'{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided
>   credentials."]}' ..
>   ---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 2 tests in 0.018s

I would really like to include login/logout in my tests as it is base of my project. If I can provide any more information that would help you help me please comment, I will be watching this thread until it is solved, I have nothing better to do :)

EDIT:

It seems like the problem is not tied to testing...

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> User.objects.create(username="test1", password="qwe123qwe")
>>> r = post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/", data={'username': 'test1', 'password': 'qwe123qwe'})
>>> r
<Response [400]>
>>> r.content
b'{"non_field_errors":["Unable to log in with provided credentials."]}'
```

For superuser (manage.py createsuperuser) it works fine

```
>>> r = post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api-token-auth/", data={'username': 'root', 'password': 'qwe123qwe'})
>>> r.content
b'{"token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InJvb3QiLCJleHAiOjE1MTc2NzQ4OTMsImVtYWlsIjoid0B3LnBsIn0.hox4-aggdWB5xG0HNe3vUeVAiVZTPbqe373fdVaERWI"}'
```

Answer (score 2):

All right, if anyone cares the problem was I was using

```
User.objects.create().
```

The proper method to create user is

```
User.objects.create_user()
```

Comment: An extra information about why this is need: `create_user` uses `set_password` method (which does the hashing on the password) on `User` objects. The simple `create` will not working since the password will be stored as it is (no hashing) and then login using that password will try to match the hash of the entered password with the raw stored password which will obviously not going to match.

Answer (score 0):

I am using django rest token and using this for tests

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient

# get token
temp = APIClient()
data = {"username": "testuser", "password": "abc"}
resp = temp.post("/token-auth/", data=data, follow=True)
token = resp.data["token"]

# authenticate using the token header on other API
temp.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + token)
resp = temp.get("/getMyItems")
print("resp: " + str(resp))
```

Comment: What does `follow=True` do?